# Issue testing components with Slots with Vue and Cypress

Tags: vue.js, cypress, vuejs3

I am new to component testing and Cypress. I have been following the official documentation and examples to do some basic component testing on my project. Eventually, I stumbled upon a case where I wanted to test a simple component I wrote which accepts a single slot (`default`) and since it was awfully similar to an example provided in the `@cypress/vue` repository, I took the liberty to copy the code and adjust it to my liking.

However, while the first test passes and mounts without issue, when I try to mount the component being tested passing it a default slot, I get a type error with `Cannot convert undefined or null to object`. Since then, I went through Vue and Vue-Testing examples and I do not seem to figure out what I am doing wrong when invoking the mount function. Below are my code snippets for the souls who can help me on this one.

**BaseButton**

```
<template>
  <a role="button" class="btn btn-primary">
    <slot />
  </a>
</template>
```

**BaseButton.spec.ts**

```
import BaseButton from '@/components/BaseButton.vue'
import { mount } from '@cypress/vue'

describe('BaseButton', () => {
  context('when slots are not passed', () => {
    it('renders nothing', () => {
      mount(BaseButton)
      cy.get('a').should('have.text', '')
    })
  })

  context('when slots are passed', () => {
    it('renders slots', () => {
      mount(BaseButton, {
        slots: {
          default: 'Test Button',
        },
      })

      cy.get('a').should('have.text', 'Test Button')
    })

    it('renders scopedSlots', () => {
      mount(BaseButton, {
        slots: {
          default: '<template #default="props"><p>Yay! {{props.content}}</p></template>',
        },
      })

      cy.contains('Yay! Scoped content!').should('be.visible')
      cy.contains('Nothing used the Scoped content!').should('not.exist')
    })
  })
})
```

Here is the [official example](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/develop/npm/vue/cypress/component/basic/slots/Card.spec.js) I based the code on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
mount(BaseButton, {
   slots: {
      default: {
          render: () => "Test Button"
      }
   }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also simplify it

```js
mount(BaseButton, {
   slots: {
      default:() => "Test Button"
   }
})
```